# nginx error can't acces https

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, ubuntu-18.04

my domain is: http://farihulrouf.red

I ran this command:

```sh
$ sudo certbot --nginx -d farihulrouf.red -d www.farihulrouf.red
```

```
server {

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name farihulrouf.red www.farihulrouf.red;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
         location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;

        }


    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/farihulrouf.red/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/farihulrouf.red/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}

server {
    if ($host = www.farihulrouf.red) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = farihulrouf.red) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        server_name farihulrouf.red www.farihulrouf.red;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot




}
```

i am not able to open my site on HTTPS:// even after installing and configuring Let’s Encrypt. Please guide, Thank you!

Comment: Are there problems inside /var/log/nginx/error.log? How is the output of netstat regarding port 443?

Comment: Please post the output of the command `nginx -T`.